# If $(8+3\sqrt{7})^n = I + F $ where $ I $ is integer and $F $ is proper fraction, what is $I$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am beginner to Binomial Theorem and I want to find out weather $I$ is even or odd in $$(8+3\sqrt{7})^n= I+F$$ if it can be expressed as a sum of an Integer $I$ and a proper fraction $F$

How could I find out ?

Comment: By proper fraction do you mean that $0< F<1$? Because $(8+3\sqrt{7})^n$ is irrational, $F$ will never be rational while $I$ is an integer. Also, what have you tried for this problem?

Comment: @Carl Yes $ 0<F<1$ and I am unable to proceed in this question.

Comment: Why do you assume it must be even or odd? Anyway it odd for n = 0 or 1.  And it's odd for n= 2.

Comment: @fleablood This is the demand of question

Answer (score 0):

let set $a=8+3\sqrt{7}\quad$ and $\quad\bar a=8-3\sqrt{7}$

From $(a-8)^2=63$ you deduce $a,\bar a$ are roots of $x^2-16x+1=0$.

Which would be the characteristic equation of the linear recurrence relation

$\begin{cases} f(0)=2\\f(1)=16\\f(n)=16f(n-1)-f(n-2)\end{cases}\quad$ where $f(n)=a^n+{\bar a}^n$

Now remark that $\bar a\approx 0.0627$ thus $\bar a^n\to 0$ extremely quickly.

So $f(n)\sim a^n$.

To be more precise since $\bar a>0$ and since $f(n)$ is an integer number, we have $\lfloor a^n\rfloor=I=f(n)-1$

Since $f(n)$ is even (by induction we only multiply and subtract even terms), so $I$ is odd.

Comment: Instead of "tends to 0 very quickly" wouldn't be enough to show that $\bar a^n < 1$ (which is obvious). This gives $f(n) > a^n = f(n) - \bar a^n > f(n)-1$ so $f(n)-1 < a^n < f(n)$

Comment: @cyanide well, I think it is trivial since $0<\bar a^n<\frac 12$ then $\lfloor a^n\rfloor = \lfloor f(n)-\bar a^n\rfloor=f(n)-1$ (we can deal with the case $n=0$ apart).

Comment: Yes, I've realized that and fixed. Indeed, "tends very quickly" doesn't look convincing enough

Answer (score 0):

Notice that 
$$\begin{align}
(8 +3 \sqrt{7})^n + (8 - 3 \sqrt{7})^n &= \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} 8 ^i (3 \sqrt{7})^{n-i} + \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} (-1)^i 8 ^i (3 \sqrt{7})^{n-i} \\
&= 2 \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2i} 8^{2i} 3^{2(n-i)} 7^{n-i} \qquad \text{(the odd numbered terms cancel out)}\\
&= 2 N
\end{align}$$
where $N$ is a positive integer.  Since $8 - 3 \sqrt{7} \approx 0.06$, we have
$$(8 +3 \sqrt{7})^n + \epsilon = 2N $$
where $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

So the integer part of $(8 +3 \sqrt{7})^n$  is odd.